# Is vertically lining up code in jQuery considered harmful?

Tags: jquery, jslint

This code:

```
if (this.config.imageTarget) {
    this.caption = $('<div />')
           .addClass('finaff-lightbox-caption')
                   .html(content.html())
                   .appendTo(this.wrapper)
                   .hide(); // starts out hidden

    this.captionSpacer = $('<div>&nbsp;</div>')
                         .appendTo(this.contentContainer)
                         .hide();
```

...causes JSLint to hit the roof. It says:

```
  if (this.config.imageTarget) {
  58                      this.caption = $('<div />')
  59                                     .addClass('finaff-lightbox-caption')
      ==========================^
      lint warning: unexpected end of line; it is ambiguous whether these lines are part of the same statement
  60                                     .html(content.html())
      ===================================^
      lint warning: unexpected end of line; it is ambiguous whether these lines are part of the same statement
  61                                     .appendTo(this.wrapper)
      ===================================^
      lint warning: unexpected end of line; it is ambiguous whether these lines are part of the same statement
  62                                     .hide();
```

Is it really necessary to collapse this sort of code together like so:

```
. . .
this.caption = $('<div />').addClass('finaff-lightbox-caption').html(content.html()).appendTo(this.wrapper).hide();
. . .
```

?

Separating it out by lining up the dots makes sense to me; makes it easier to read/grok. I hope this is just JSLint playing the white-gloved mother-in-law.

Comment: JSLint is often unnecessarily strict—and more often than not it shouldn't be hailed as the *only* gold standard of debugging JS. Try [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) instead (which, *ta-da*, your code checks out perfectly fine, sans the `$` undefined variable, but that's normal as it doesn't know you are using it as a jQuery alias). I would prefer using line-breaks when the methods chain exceeds a line that comfortably fits the width of the viewport, for better readability — and also very useful to indicate which "level" you are on when transcending the DOM :)

Comment: ... and that's where JSHint came from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is set the `white` option (for whitespace) to true.

This code lints at [JSLint.com](http://jslint.com/):

```
/*jslint white:true */
/*global $, content */
if (this.config.imageTarget) {
    this.caption = $('<div />')
           .addClass('finaff-lightbox-caption')
                   .html(content.html())
                   .appendTo(this.wrapper)
                   .hide(); // starts out hidden

    this.captionSpacer = $('<div>&nbsp;</div>')
                         .appendTo(this.contentContainer)
                         .hide();
}
```

The only changes I made were:

- Set the jslint directive `white` to `true` (tolerate non-draconian whitespace rules)
- Added the `global` line for jQuery and `content`

  - not sure what `content` is;
  - Note: using `global` is almost certainly *not* the best way to handle `content`
- Added a closing `}` bracket for your `if`.